# PyCharm - how to suspend all threads

Tags: python, multithreading, debugging, pycharm, suspend

We're using PyCharm 5.0.1 for multi-thread debugging. 
When it stops at a break point, only the specific thread stops while all the other continue. This makes it hard to "freeze the moment" and check params values, and the current state of the other threads.
Is it possible to suspend all the thread while one of them has stopped on a breakpoint?

Is this possible on the newest Pycharm 2016 or the [latest] Pycharm version?

Comment: Why is the title of the question using "PyCharm 3" and body of the question says PyCharm 5.0.1?

Comment: You are right, fixed, thank you.

Comment: FYI, there is a brand new version of Pycharm just released: 2016.1, haven't tested yet to see if it helps with this but it does list a number of improvements for debugging in the release notes.

Comment: Its an open and very important (imho) functionality, so changed the question to also ask about the latest version of Pycharm....

Answer (score 13):

According to [this thread](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-2431) this is possible after PyCharm 2016.2:

Elizaveta Shashkova  27 Jul 2016:

> The new feature has appeared in PyCharm 2016.2: breakpoint thread
>   suspend policy. You can go to Run | View breakpoints, select the
>   breakpoint and change its threads suspend policy: "Thread" or "All".
>   Also you can set the default policy for all your breakpoints.

Comment: This does not always work. For example if one of your threads is waiting in a C-level function (e.g. `socket.recv()`) then even with "All" set, the impacted thread will not be interrupted and the stack pane will show "Frames not available in non-suspended state".