# PDB - How to suspend all threads

Tags: python, multithreading, debugging, pdb

When a multithreaded Python program hits a breakpoint, the relevant thread will stop but the other threads will continue running. In some cases, this can be an obstacle to debugging.

For example, in `test.py`:

```py
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep


def thread1():
    while True:
        sleep(1)
        print("hello")


def thread2():
    breakpoint()


Thread(target=thread1).start()
Thread(target=thread2).start()
```

Will lead to the following debugging session:

```
$ python test.py 
--Return--
> /.../test.py(12)thread2()->None
-> breakpoint()
(Pdb) hello
hello
hello
hello
...
```

As you can see, the `print` statement from `thread1` is disturbing the debugging session in `thread2`.

In PyCharm's debugger, it's possible to suspend all threads: [PyCharm - how to suspend all threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35772638/pycharm-how-to-suspend-all-threads)

Is it possible to suspend all threads in PDB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't currently supported.  The `pdb` debugger is not described as being good for debugging multi-threaded applications.

- [Issue 21281](https://bugs.python.org/issue21281) - this is a 6 year old request for enhancement to support stopping all threads when a breakpoint is triggered.  It hasn't received much attention.
- [Issue 41571](https://bugs.python.org/issue41571) - this is a more recent request for enhancement to add better thread support to pdb.
- The [PythonDebugTools](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDebuggingTools) page in the Python Wiki lists debuggers and IDEs that support debugging of multi-threaded applications.